# Alternating and colored lines in php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to apply color on alternate lines in the following code in PHP, but I already tried in various shapes and examples here in the forum and it did not solve. I need only leave one white line, and another gray, filling in according to the mysql query. I would like to make this list without using CSS. Can someone help?

```
 <style type="text/css">
  .whiteBackground { background-color: #fff; }
  .grayBackground { background-color: #ccc; }
 </style>

<table class="table-bordered" style="text-align: center; margin-left: -50px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; margin-top: 20px;"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">
  <table class="table-bordered" style="text-align: center; margin-left: -50px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; margin-top: 20px;"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" align="center">

              <thead>

                  <tr>

                      <th style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Client</th>
                      <th style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Tech</th>
                      <th style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Status</th>
                      <th style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Data</th>
                      <th style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Start</th>
                      <th style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">End</th>
                      <th style="font-size: 1em; padding: 5px;">Total Hours</th>


                  </tr>

              </thead>

              <tbody>     

           <?php

                 $x++; 

                $class = ($x%2 == 0)? 'whiteBackground': 'graybackground';

                echo "<tr class='$class'>";


                  foreach ($os as $c) {

                   $query = "SELECT nome from users where idUsers=$c->users_id";

            $data= $this->db->query($query)->result();

                     echo '<tr >';
                         echo '<td >' . $c->nameclient . '</td>';
                         echo '<td >' . $data[0]->name . '</td>';
                         echo '<td >' . $c->status . '</td>';
                         echo '<td >' . date('d/m/Y',  strtotime($c->startDate)) . '</td>';
                         echo '<td >' . $c->startTime . '</td>';
                         echo '<td >' . $c->endTime . '</td>';
            $time_diff = strtotime($c->endTime) - strtotime($c->startTime);
                         $var= $time_diff/60;


                             echo '<td >'.date('H:i', mktime(0,$var)).'</td>'; 
                             echo '</tr>';

                              }

                  ?>
```

Comment: Don't try it with PHP. Instead, use [CSS: even/odd, or nth child rules](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

Comment: Can't see where were you trying to set the colors with PHP. Also, as @aynber said, it's not the best approach.

Comment: check answers using `%` [PHP doc modulo](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.operators.arithmetic.php) -> even/odd + CSS (1st User Contributed Notes shows you a way to do it) EDIT: @aynber approach might even be sweeter :)

Comment: I updated code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show the example of using % (or Mod) to alternate the background color on a simple array.

```
$arr = array("fred","tim","bob","jimmy");
echo "<table>";
$i=1;
foreach ($arr as $row) {
  $class = ($i % 2) ? " odd": " even"; //even or odd?
  echo "<tr class=" . $class . ">";
  echo "<td>" . $row . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
}
echo "</table>"
?>
<style type="text/css">
  .even, .odd {
    color:white;
  }
  .even {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .odd {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

And, how to do it in purely CSS. (IE 9 or greater: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```
$arr = array("fred","tim","bob","jimmy");
echo "<table>";
$i=1;
foreach ($arr as $row) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
}
echo "</table>"
?>
<style type="text/css">
  .even, .odd {
    color:white;
  }
  table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think many people use the HTML attribut bgcolor anymore, but you can use it in the TR tag bgcolor="#cccccc".  Or you can just use an inline style of background-color: #cccccc;

```
$highlight = false;

foreach ($os as $c) 
{
    $query = "SELECT nome from users where idUsers=$c->users_id";
    $data= $this->db->query($query)->result();
    $time_diff = strtotime($c->endTime) - strtotime($c->startTime);
    $var= $time_diff/60;

    $highlight = !$highlight;

    echo '
    <tr '.($highlight ? 'bgcolor="#cccccc"' : '').'>
        <td >' . $c->nameclient . '</td>
        <td >' . $data[0]->name . '</td>
        <td >' . $c->status . '</td>
        <td >' . date('d/m/Y',  strtotime($c->startDate)) . '</td>
        <td >' . $c->startTime . '</td>
        <td >' . $c->endTime . '</td>
        <td >'.date('H:i', mktime(0,$var)).'</td> 
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: The code presented error in this way. I think it has something to do with this part; {echo '
    <tr '.($highlight ? 'bgcolor="#cccccc" : "").'>}

Comment: Apologies... I corrected the error.
The example does not use any CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your css to this

```
<style type="text/css">
  /* .whiteBackground { background-color: #fff; } */
  /* .grayBackground { background-color: #ccc; } */
  tbody tr:even{background-color:#fff;}
  tbody tr:odd{background-color:#ccc;}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi! Don't work on array
Maybe in a simple table in html

Comment: I think, you don't need to add styles to the array (because the arrays dont have styles), you need to use the right css to color the `tr`'s